# How can I make a div appear onclick using Javascript?

Tags: javascript

I want to make 2 buttons appear onclick. How can I do this with Javascript? The code is supposed to ask a user "How their doing?" and then give them 2 options to choose from.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <script>
        function helloName() {
            // GET THE USERS INPUT
            var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;

            // GREET USER WITH THEIR NAME
            document.write("Hello " + userName + ", How are you doing today?");

            // GIVE USER AN OPTION TO SELECT HOW THEIR FEELING 
            document.getElementById("show-buttons").style.display = 'block';
        };

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <h1>JS Skills Test</h1>
    <label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
    <button onclick="helloName()">Click Me</button>

    <div id="show-buttons" style="display: none;">
        <button id="bad">I'm not doing to well</button>
        <button id="good">I'm doing wonderful</button>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You cant do `document.write` after the dom has finished loading.

Comment: You can hide the 2 buttons with css. And once you get the user input just get the the correct button by Id or Class name and change the correct buttons css hidden property to unhidden. Maybe that will work for you’re usecase

Answer (score 7):

When you do `document.write()`, all the dom element will be deleted, try this:

```js
function helloName() {
  // GET THE USERS INPUT
  var userName = document.getElementById("name").value;

  // GREET USER WITH THEIR NAME
  document.getElementById("message").innerText = "Hello " + userName + ", How are you doing today?";

  // GIVE USER AN OPTION TO SELECT HOW THEIR FEELING 
  document.getElementById("show-buttons").style.display = 'block';
};
```

```html
<h1>JS Skills Test</h1>
<label for="name">Enter Your Name</label>
<input id="name" type="text" placeholder="Enter Your Name">
<button onclick="helloName()">Click Me</button>
<div id="message"></div>

<div id="show-buttons" style="display: none;">
  <button id="bad">I'm not doing to well</button>
  <button id="good">I'm doing wonderful</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, I didn't even notice this and just wrote a toggle functionality on click of the button. Since that was the question but upvoted your answer cause it both makes the message visible and will make the buttons wrapper div visible. Very thoroughly read and answered the question with a completely working example! So /ignore my answer below although it does answer the original question which was making a div appear on click of a button, my function toggles display: none/block because the original code was written with the display property. I would use visibility: visible/hidden;

Answer (score 0):

You add an event listener on click on the div and add or change css class which contains visibility or display properties.

```
function helloName() {
  const x =        
    document.getElementById("show-buttons");
  if (x.style.display === "none") {
      x.style.display = "block";
  } else {
      x.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

You could also use style **visibility: visible;** or **visibility: hidden;**

This can be found simple on [w3schools.com](http://w3schools.com) btw.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
function helloName() {
  document.getElementById('message').innerText = "Hello"+ userName + ", How are you doing today?";
  var x = document.getElementById("show-buttons");
  x.style.display="block";
  }
```